# For A New Computer w/o a OS, Can I Install It Through A USB DVD Reader?

Tags: computer-building, desktop-computer

My budget's short on my computer build and the DVD burner couldn't make it. There's no pre-installed OS on it so I have to do this on my own. Can I use a USB DVD burner to install the OS?

Would this require USB drivers? (Which I cannot install as there is no OS on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install any OS that your computer supports. **No problems at all**.

They won't require any drivers to begin with but BIOS on your computer must support USB booting (if your computer is relatively new, it will support USB booting), you can just put a bootable DVD in your USB-DVD reader and you should be good to go (Windows, Linux, Mac OS, any bootable DVD).

Comment: This SHOULD work, but I have seen this fail due to awkward firmware implementations in USB DVD drives.  Hope it works though.  If it doesn't you can always move the DVD onto a thumbdrive.  I have had more success that way

Comment: =) Brilliant suggestion about the thumbdrive. Forgot about that technique from ages ago. (Will upvote this later on when I get my votes back.) ... It's not possible to use a Mac OS disk, isn't it?

Comment: Mac OS disk from thumbdrive should work...ultimately it's just a custom nix distro that was originally designed for PPC instead of x86. it may require tweaking though